# font-face line-break and position problems

Tags: wordpress, font-face

I'm having a very strange problem with my font-face fonts.

I've got 3 wordpress websites all at the same server but on 3 different domains. On each of these website I use font-face fonts.

Sometimes my font-face fonts removes line-breaks from the text and the position has a left margin. When I get this problem, the problem occures on all 3 websites. When I upload my stylesheet on 1 of my website the problem solved, also on my other websites.

It seems like cache problem or maybe a Wordpress problem but I'm not sure.

Anybody familiar with this problem?

Comment: Font's can be included in a few different ways. Please share your CSS and HTML so we can see what your actual implementation looks like. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you disable @font-face do you still get the same issue? My guess is yes. It sounds like an issue with WordPress' built in wpautop messing with your line-breaks. I know it's a bit tricky to get the hang of at first.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop

It would be a lot easier to help if you linked your sites or provided some code to look at.

Comment: I've disable font-face for some elements. The problem just occures and only the elements wich uses font-face have the problems.

Comment: When I upload the css the problems solved but after a while the problems are back...